# Forgot to add cornstarch to my dough which is already proofing

Tags: dough

I am in the middle of making cinnamon rolls and the recipe called for cornstarch in the dough recipe. Well I forgot it and the dough is already proofing. Do I need to make my dough again or can this be salvaged some how?

Comment: How much cornstarch? Do you know what the cornstarch is supposed to bring to the recipe? With some more details, it may be easier to answer just how much of a disaster this is (from "probably barely noticeable" to "a completely different texture")...

Comment: 1/2 cup. The recipe is trying to attain a flour mixture that mimics cake flour but a little less. They are wanting a protein content somewhere in between cake flour and all purpose flour. They found this helped hold the roll shape once baked

Comment: Can I try and add it in once proofed or would it be better to just leave it out at this point?

Comment: @Jaala, can you please post an answer (or at least a comment) on what you did and how it turned out?

Comment: 1/2 cup will have very different effects depending on how much flour you've got as well

Answer (score 3):

If the dough is proofing correctly, which it should be if the cornstarch is the only thing missing and everything else is correct, then you should be fine without it.

Depending on how much cornstarch was asked for the texture will be different, probably a tad less tender. But it shouldn't be anything that ruins the dough.

If you can get sweet dough like that through its first proof with good rise it's pretty much smooth sailing after that so I wouldn't worry about it.

If you want you can post the recipe and I'll take a gander at it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I ended up adding about 1/4 cup of cornstarch after proofing (half of what the recipe called for). It definitly changed the texture of the dough as I was adding it in which is why I didn't add it all in there. The rolls came out just fine. They were pretty dense but the taste was delicious. Will have to see what they are like when the dough is made with all the ingredients at the right time.

Comment: @Jaala Hi, just if you're interested, I've been making a lot of cinnamon rolls lately. If you want to avoid putting such a large amount of cornstarch in there, all purpose works great on its own. If anything when I tried to make a cake with that substitute the cornstarch made a very negative impact on the texture. A good way to get that gooey soft texture is to knead the dough only until it's stilly a bit tacky and very elastic, then once the buns are cut and in the container, prior to putting them in the oven, pour about half a cup of heavy cream all across the top of them.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @bobkayser! I will give it a go again and try leaving the cornstarch out all together.